# Error en syntax PHP 8

Tags: php

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente error en PHP 8

Este es mi código y antes funcionaba bien cuando tenia el XAMPP anterior a la versión actual que trabaja con PHP 8.

```
function enviocodigo($longitud)
 { 
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890'; 
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1; 
    
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) 
        $key .= $pattern{
            mt_rand(0,$max)
    }; 
    return $key;

};
```

Este es el error que me genera:

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\encuesta\index.php on line 82

Alguna ayuda para poder mejorar el código que me da error por favor.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ese código nunca funcionó en alguna versión de PHP porque la sintaxis está mal. Al final de la línea del `for` es que va la apertura de llave `{`. Elimina la llave de la línea `$key .= $pattern{` y reemplazala por `;`. La linea `mt_rand(0,$max)` también debe terminar en `;`

Comment: Hola aeportugal ya hice lo que mencionas pero ahora sale otro error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "}" in C:\xampp\htdocs\encuesta\index.php on line 84

Comment: Edité el comentario con otra corrección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde `PHP 7.*` el uso de llaves para acceder a valores de arreglos o cadenas estaba **descontinuado**. Por ejemplo:

```
$pattern = '1234567890';
echo $pattern{5};
```

Funcionaba pero lanzaba una advertencia:

> Deprecated:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c19d463e577ccca44c0297d758d40596f47225c2)</kbd>

A partir de `PHP 8.*` **se elimino definitivamente el soporte** al uso de llaves para realizar dicha acción y por eso ahora ya no funciona mas.

#### Solución:

Usar corchetes, así:

```
$key .= $pattern[mt_rand(0,$max)];
```

---

*Referencias:*

- [Cambios incompatibles hacia atrás < Migración de PHP 7.4.x a PHP 8.0.x](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration80.incompatible.php)

  > Support for deprecated curly braces for offset access has been removed.

  Traducido:

  > Se ha eliminado la compatibilidad en desuso de llaves para el acceso de compensación.